# Setting angular variable without affect each other

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm **new** in angular js and bumped ( I think ) in to simple problem. Sorry if I dublicated question, but I can't find any related topics.

I need to set `$scope` variable without affecting each other, but then I'm setting them, both are updated with the same results:

```
var defaultFilterValues = {
    show_limit: 20,
    purpose: {}
};

$scope.filter = defaultFilterValues;

console.log($scope.filter);
console.log(defaultFilterValues);
```

If I set `$scope.filter = { /* any data */ }` both results are updated, how I can isolate `defaultFilterValue` to always have primary results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not 100% sure what you are wanting but you can use `angular.copy()` to make duplicate that isn't referenced to original object

Reference [angular.copy() docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy)

```
$scope.filter = angular.copy(defaultFilterValues);
```

it will also clean out any internal hashkeys that angular adds to objects

Comment: then what exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

That is because all objects in JavaScript are copied by reference, you need

```
angular.extend($scope.filter, defaultFilterValues);
```